# Call signature of Func<TResult>.BeginInvoke

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous

I am trying to write an async operation using C# and .net 4.5/4.6, and am trying to use `Func.BeginInvoke()`

Here's what MSDN's [BeginInvoke](https://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev14.query?appId=Dev14IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(System.Func%601.BeginInvoke);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.6);k(DevLang-csharp)&rd=true) page says:

```
public virtual IAsyncResult BeginInvoke(
    AsyncCallback callback,
    Object object
)
```

Unfortunatly there's no information on what the second parameter (object) is, and the primary [MSDN Async Tutorial Page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2e08f6yc(v=vs.110).aspx) shows:

```
// Initiate the asychronous call.
        IAsyncResult result = caller.BeginInvoke(3000, 
            out threadId, null, null);
```

which isn't even a supported function definition!

Looks like the .net documentation has gotten substantially worse since last time I looked at it.

Help would be appreciated!

Comment: You should consider using `TPL` and `async/await` features for asynchronous calls in .net 4.5. `IAsyncResult` is rather complicated to be used and understood, and also is quite obsolete.

Comment: Thank you, your suggestion is better than an actual answer :)

Comment: Ahh, I need to make synchronous code asynchronous, so I'll still need the "old slog" way, but will use async/await to call it.

Comment: Why do you have such a requirement? Asynchronous calls are necessary only for IO operations and UI; otherwise you will gain no profit. (Nevertheless, you could use `Task.Run` to start some action on task pool and await it then)

Comment: I have code that interacts with a 3rd party COM library, and it currently locks up the UI when waiting on the COM component, so I'll be making an async wrapper over the top of it.  will use async/await to call the wrapper though!

Comment: Ok, it's reasonable for UI. You could use it like this:
`var result = await Task.Run(() => comComponent.SomeAction())`

Comment: Thank you Vladislav!  I also just found System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Factory.StartNew()  so both will suffice!

Comment: `Task.Run` is just a useful shortcut added in .net 4.5.1 for `Task.Factory.StartNew` with adequate arguments defaults.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the BeginInvoke object is your argument to pass into callback. It will be available as a property in the parameter for callback. I usually pass delegate itself, so I call EndInvoke on it.

Comment: In my experience, the `IAsyncResult` parameter passed to the callback is always an instance of `AsyncResult`, which exposes a property `AsyncDelegate`, so there's no need to pass the delegate directly. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1484384/622391) for an example.

Answer (score 2):

It's right on the page [Calling Synchronous Methods Asynchronously](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2e08f6yc(v=vs.110).aspx) that you link to

> The second parameter is a user-defined object that passes information into the callback method.

It arrives via the `IAsyncResult` parameter's `AsyncState` property.

The BeginInvoke method signature is different for each delegate type. The language runtime guarantees it is defined with the same arguments as the delegate type plus two additional arguments which it discusses on the second page you've linked to. You've linked to the documentation for `Func<T>` which takes no parameters, but the example uses a custom delegate type that has two parameters, therefore the signatures are different.

Answer (score 1):

`AsyncCallback` delegate has signature equivalent to `Action<object>`. The second parameter of `BeginInvoke` will be provided as argument to your callback - some state to pass.

If your delegate has some paramters, they should be passed to the async invocation also. So `BeginInvoke` will have different signatures for different types of delegate.

In tutorial this one is used:

```
public delegate string AsyncMethodCaller(int callDuration, out int threadId);
```

So in invocation

```
IAsyncResult result = caller.BeginInvoke(3000, out threadId, null, null);
```

`3000` is value of `callDuration`, `out threadId` used for `out int threadId`, while `null` and `null` are `callback` and `object`.